# Search Function didn't work

Tags: android, search, searchview

appreciate your help here. I don't why it didn't work. I have added the following function to search for user. I debug it and it appears it stucked at the filter (argo) function. My code as follows. There is nothing in the logcat error. Appreciate your help.

My code (updated code)

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class EditFriendsActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final String TAG = EditFriendsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;
    CustomAdaptor adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_friends);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);



    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
        query.setLimit(1000);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                if (e == null) {
                    // Success
                    mUsers = users;
                    String[] usernames = new String[mUsers.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for(ParseUser user : mUsers) {
                        usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                        i++;
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            EditFriendsActivity.this, 
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                            usernames);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                    addFriendCheckmarks();
                }
                else {

                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditFriendsActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.findrecipients, menu); 

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                android.content.Context context;
                context = getApplicationContext();
                Search srchContact = new Search(context, adapter, (ListView) mUsers);
                srchContact.Search(arg0);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
                return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class Search
    {
        android.content.Context context;
        CustomAdaptor tempAdptr;
        CustomAdaptor adptr;
        android.widget.ListView lstContact;
        java.util.ArrayList<ParseUser> arrMyObject;
        public Search(android.content.Context con , CustomAdaptor adp , android.widget.ListView lst )
        {
            context = con;
            arrMyObject = new java.util.ArrayList<ParseUser>();
            tempAdptr = new CustomAdaptor(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, arrMyObject);
            adptr = adp;
            lstContact = lst;
        }
        public void Search(String strSearch)
        {
            lstContact.setAdapter(tempAdptr);
            if(strSearch.equals(""))
            {
                lstContact.setAdapter(adptr);
                return ; 
            }
            arrMyObject.removeAll(arrMyObject) ; 
            for(int i = 0 ; i < mUsers.size() ; i++)
            {
                if(mUsers.get(i).getUsername().contains(strSearch)) 
                {
                    //Add item to your list
                }
            }
            tempAdptr.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


public class CustomAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> {
    android.content.Context context;
    int resId;
    java.util.ArrayList<ParseUser> arrData;
    public CustomAdaptor(Context ac, int resource, java.util.ArrayList<ParseUser> data) {
        super(ac, resource, data);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         context = ac;
            resId = resource;
            arrData = data;
    }


    @Override
    public android.view.View getView(final int position,android.view.View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        try
        {
            ParseUser member = arrData.get(position);
            android.view.LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            android.view.View Row =inflater.inflate(resId, parent , false);
            // Set Your XML file
            return Row;
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code that can be useful:
In this code , we have several class:
First:Search class that search in a list and show result in list view
Second: CustomAdapter that prepare list view
Third: Main that call Search function in Search class

```
public class Search
{
    android.content.Context context;
    CustomAdaptor tempAdptr;
    CustomAdaptor adptr;
    android.widget.ListView lstContact;
    java.util.ArrayList<MyObject> arrMyObject;
    public SearchContact(android.content.Context con , CustomAdaptor adp , android.widget.ListView lst )
    {
        context = con;
        arrMyObject = new java.util.ArrayList<MyObject>();
        tempAdptr = new CustomAdaptor(context, R.layout.contact_row, arrMyObject);
        adptr = adp;
        lstContact = lst;
    }
    public void Search(String strSearch)
    {
        lstContact.setAdapter(tempAdptr);
        if(strSearch.equals(""))
        {
            lstContact.setAdapter(adptr);
            return ; 
        }
        arrMyObject.removeAll(arrMyObject) ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < MainActivity.GetArrMyObject().size() ; i++)
        {
            if(arrlist.get(i).contains(strSearch)) 
            {
                //Add item to your list
            }
        }
        tempAdptr.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class CustomAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {

android.content.Context context;
int resId;
java.util.ArrayList<MyObject> arrData;
public ContactAdaptor(android.content.Context ac, int resource , java.util.ArrayList<MyObject> data ) {
    super(ac, resource, data);
    context = ac;
    resId = resource;
    arrData = data;
}
@Override
public android.view.View getView(final int position,android.view.View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) 
{
    try
    {
        MyObject member = arrData.get(position);
        android.view.LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        android.view.View Row =inflater.inflate(resId, parent , false);
        // Set Your XML file
        return Row;
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Now you can use this code in main:

```
SearchContact srchContact = new SearchContact(context, adptr, arraylist);
    srchContact.Search(YourObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your method, but it appear now no error while search but it didn't filter the search based on what I type. I updated cope above, would you mine to help me check what I have done wrong? Thanks very much. Sorry I am really new here so appreciate your guidance.

Comment: what do you want to filter?<br>Explain your project!!

Comment: I am trying to filter users retrieved from Parse. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Any filter can be done in if that located within  for in Search function. when you read an item from list you can put that in a new object and check your filter option. if need you can add that object to arraylist